# finding dynamic control

Tags: jquery

I have Telerik grid control, there I have an edit control like update and cancel buttons and so on.

The edit controls are shown automatically when I edit image click, no manual coding used to invoke the controls. Therefore my problem is I have to validate the input control when I update button click. The controls are created dynamically. So I used its client id value to make it functioning. But I could not do. I used the below code.

```
   $('#RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl05_btnUpdate').click(function() {
        alert("hai..Update Button");
        //Here I have to validate input controls
    });
```

-Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is / what you want

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [partial attribute selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue) to find an element whose `id` attribute contains the ID you've assigned to the control:

```
$('[id$=btnUpdate]').click(funciton () {
  alert('hai ... Update Button');
});
```

This will bind to any element whose `id` attribute ends with `'btnUpdate'`.

If your grid control is dynamic, you might have to use the [`live()` event binder](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) like so:

```
$('[id$=btnUpdate]').live('click', funciton () {
  alert('hai ... Update Button');
});
```

Comment: You might want to try using `live()` instead, if your grid is dynamic. I've updated my answer.